# Bindings not working in Listview Xamarin MVVM

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, binding

I have this mysterious problem that nobody seems to be able to figure out. I am building an app with Xamarin and classlibraries, with the MVVM pattern.

I have a listview that is connected to a list of course but will not connect to properties, when I try to bind the labels. I have tried everything, removed all the code bit by bit to see if that changed something but nothing works.
I have sat with this issue for days and would be incredibly thankful if someone can help me.

I have checked and the list successfully makes it to the UI, I suspect the error is in the xaml code but I post most of the code if it could be something else.

Page:

```
        <StackLayout>

        <!-- Searchbar  -->
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar 
                TextColor="black"
                FontSize="24"
                PlaceholderColor="Black"
                Placeholder="Sök lista..." 
                Margin="0,5,30,10"
                SearchCommand="{Binding PerformSearch}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        
        <!-- Listview of inventory lists  -->
        <ListView BackgroundColor="#7EA0B7" 
              SeparatorColor="#7EA0B7"
                  x:Name="listView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfLists}"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              SelectionMode="None">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>  
                    <Grid Padding="5">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="white">
                            <StackLayout>
                                
                            <Label 
                                TextColor="Black" 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"  
                                Text="{Binding ListName}" <----- can't debug cause it can't find it
                                FontSize="Large"/>
                                
                            <Label 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                Text="{Binding DateSent}"<----- can't debug cause it can't find it                                FontSize="Medium"/>

                                    <Label 
                                FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                                Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                                Text="{Binding Date}" <----- can't debug cause it can't find it
                                FontSize="Medium"/>

           
                                </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

        <!-- Create new list button  -->
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="+ Skapa ny lista"
                    Margin="8"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    FontSize="24"
                    FontFamily="PTC55F.ttf#ptc55f"
                    BackgroundColor="#AAC0AA"
                    TextColor="black"
                    BorderColor="Black"
                    BorderWidth="2"
                    Command="{Binding NavigateCreateListCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs

```
    public partial class InventoryStartPage : ContentPage
    {
        public InventoryStartPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            BindingContext = new InventoryStartViewModel(new ListManager(new MockListRepo());


        }
```

Vm

```
        public ObservableCollection<ListModel> ListOfLists { get; set; }


        private ListManager _manager;

        public InventoryStartViewModel(ListManager manager, NavigationServices navigationService)
        {
            
            _manager = manager;
          
            ListOfLists = _manager.GetLists();
           


        }
```

Manager

```
 public class ListManager
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ListModel> ListList = new ObservableCollection<ListModel>();
        private readonly IMockListRepo _mockRepo;

        public ListManager(IMockListRepo mockRepo)
        {
            _mockRepo = mockRepo;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ListModel> GetLists()
        {
            foreach (var list in _mockRepo.GetAllLists())
            {
                ListList.Add(list);
            }

            return ListList;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your ListModel look like?

Comment: `public class ListModel

    {

        
        public int ListId { get; set; }

        public string ListName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateSent { get; set; }

    }`

Comment: @awkward_coder add break point to check whether the ListOfLists  has data? I test your code, having no problem.

Comment: I have, so it still is weird that it won't work. when I had the listview connected to a list mocked in the viewmodel from the beginning, the bindings worked.

Comment: try changing one of your Labels to use a hardcoded value for Text - this will validate that the ListView has data and the template layout is working

Comment: Thank you, but I already did this, and I can see the list is there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! After hours of ripping my hair out because of this binding problem. Here comes the solution my friends!

```
        <ListView 
            BackgroundColor="White"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfArticles}"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
              SelectionMode="None">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10" 
                         x:DataType="model:ArticleRegistrationModel"> <--------THISSSS
                            <Label Text="{Binding ArticleId}" 
                          
                            FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ArticleName}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            FontSize="13" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding  }" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            FontSize="13" />

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>


        </ListView>
```

ADDING  x:DataType="model:ArticleRegistrationModel" to the Stacklayout surrounding the labels finally fixed it. First only two props showed up, but after a build they all were there.

Hope this solves it for somebody else aswell.